# how to change the name of image in model file in paperclip before saving in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip to save images in s3. The following is the code in my model

```
has_attached_file :pic, :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
    :url => '/image/file/:basename.:extension',
    :path => '/image/file/:basename.:extension',
    :bucket => 'Test'
```

And the problem is whenever i save the image with same name, the image gets replaced if there is already an image with that name. I wanted to change the name of the file. I am saving the image during the creation of new item. So can i able to use the id of the item as name of the file so that the image will be unique? If yes then how can i do it? please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you:

[Generating a unique file path with Polymorphic Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146848/generating-a-unique-file-path-with-polymorphic-paperclip)

http://trevorturk.com/2009/03/22/randomize-filename-in-paperclip/

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the one like given in the first link.